# Truffle migrate Error: PollingBlockTracker

Tags: truffle, infura, truffle-migration, avalanche

I'm trying to deploy a contract on Avalanche Fuji testnet using Truffle. Here is my truffle config:

```
require('dotenv').config();
const mnemonic = process.env["MNEMONIC"];
const infuraUrl = process.env["INFURA_URL"]; //https://avalanche-fuji.infura.io/v3/...
 
const HDWalletProvider = require('@truffle/hdwallet-provider');

module.exports = {

  networks: {
    development: {
      host: "127.0.0.1",
      port: 8545,
      network_id: "*"
    },
    fuji: {
      provider: () => new HDWalletProvider(mnemonic, infuraUrl),
      network_id: "43113",
      gas: 5000000,
      networkCheckTimeout: 1000000,    
      timeoutBlocks: 200,
    }
  },
  ...
  compilers: {
    solc: {
      version: "0.8.13",      // Fetch exact version from solc-bin
    }
  }
};
```

When I run `truffle migrate --network fuji`, I get the following error:

```
Compiling your contracts...
===========================
> Everything is up to date, there is nothing to compile.

/Users/me/Projects/myProject/node_modules/eth-block-tracker/src/polling.js:51
        const newErr = new Error(`PollingBlockTracker - encountered an error while attempting to update latest block:\n${err.stack}`)
                       ^
Error: PollingBlockTracker - encountered an error while attempting to update latest block:
undefined
    at PollingBlockTracker._performSync (/Users/me/Projects/myProject/node_modules/eth-block-tracker/src/polling.js:51:24)
    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)
    at runNextTicks (node:internal/process/task_queues:64:3)
    at listOnTimeout (node:internal/timers:540:9)
    at processTimers (node:internal/timers:514:7)
UnhandledRejections detected
Promise {
  <rejected> {
    code: -32603,
    message: 'Socket connection timeout',
    data: { originalError: [Object] }
  }
} {
  code: -32603,
  message: 'Socket connection timeout',
  data: { originalError: { code: 'ERR_SOCKET_CONNECTION_TIMEOUT' } }
}
Promise {
  <rejected> {
    code: -32603,
    message: 'Socket connection timeout',
    data: { originalError: [Object] }
  }
} {
  code: -32603,
  message: 'Socket connection timeout',
  data: { originalError: { code: 'ERR_SOCKET_CONNECTION_TIMEOUT' } }
}
Promise {
  <rejected> {
    code: -32603,
    message: 'Socket connection timeout',
    data: { originalError: [Object] }
  }
} {
  code: -32603,
  message: 'Socket connection timeout',
  data: { originalError: { code: 'ERR_SOCKET_CONNECTION_TIMEOUT' } }
}
```

Does anyone know what the issue is? Is it the Infuria API?

Answer (score 0):

run `npx truffle migrate --network goerli` instead of `truffle migrate --network goerli`.
This Worked for me.